# Nativescript Vue - Showing a modal based on a dynamic import

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import, nativescript

I want to import and load a component, based on a string variable.

```
 Vue.component(this.componentName, () => import('./' + this.componentName`));
 this.$showModal(this.componentName);
```

The code above doesn't work properly, and loads a transparent modal. `componentName` is "Text" -*which is a string*- in this case.

If I import the modal regularly, it works fine. e.g:

```
import Text from './Text'
this.$showModal(Text);
```

But if I try to call it with variable name, it says: `'Unknown custom element: <Text> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.'`

Actually Text component name is already defined in the component.

I also tried the code below, but it gave the same output with first one -*transparent empty modal*-:

```
let component = Vue.component(this.componentName, () => import('./' + this.componentName));
this.$showModal(component);
```

How can I properly load a component based on a string variable and set it to the `showModal()`?

Note: showModal's first parameter is *{typeof Vue} component*

Comment: Your import statement can not be dynamic, webpack wouldn't know whether or not it should bundle the component into app. Use the static import and return the component class conditionally, that might work.

Comment: How to get the component class with a static import then? Or do you mean setting the component to a variable in a condition and use it in the showModal's parameter? Yeah, that one works.

Comment: Yes, I meant that. Making your import statement static and assigning the component  from a variable.